# Multi level permissions for custom list

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, permissions, custom-list

I have a custom list I am looking for some permissions guidance.
I have three groups which need to see list items

Item Creator - user who has created the list item
Item Authorizers - check and authorize the list content - this person is selected by the admin to be the authorizer - based on individual merit
List Admin - owners and administrators of the list

The List Admin require unhindered access
The Item Authorizes are invited - drawn from a user group
The Item Creator can be anyone.

What is my best approach?

Just as a foot note - I have tried using the views and filtering via some list fields and setting the criteria to [ME].
I have some success with getting the creator exclusion I need but I am not sure if there is a field I can use that would allow me to do this for the Item Authorizer & List Admin. These fields would need to the be set to the unique groups and hidden.

Field used for Item Creator
Creator - Created by - [ME]

Answer (score 0):

You need to turn on Content Approval in your SharePoint list.

Go to list settings > Versioning Settings.

There you can configure you settings as below:

[image]

Additionally, you can also turn on item level permission.

Go to list settings > Advanced settings. There configure the settings as below:

[image]

The screenshots are pretty much self explanatory, but if you have questions, just comment here :)

Comment: How is version control going to solve this issue?

Comment: You are not turning on version control,  you are turning on content approval. Its different such that here you get to specify which users are allowed to access items, see screenshot 1. When you configure the settings as in screenshot 1 , only the admins, item creator and the approvers get to see the items.

Comment: Thanks for Explaining. I will give it a shot. I'll get back.